# Estimating risk in linear regression analysis

Tags: r, regression

I am relative new in regression analysis. I would like to know, if there is a way in regression analyis to estimate the risk or calculate the risk for future values?

An example:

We want to predict the export of a country for next year. We can use linear regression to estimate the export value for the next year. This value may be influenced by another parameter for example Weather catastrophe. Is there any way to estimate such a risk in linear regrssion?

Comment: Do you have data that includes weather catastrophes?

Comment: Actualy not, it is only an assumption

Comment: regression is based on using the data at hand to infer the relationship between variables and consequently generate predictions. If you have no data at hand (about weather catastrophes) you can't infer a relationship nor make any predictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a multiple regression, using weather catastrophe. I am not sure how you are measuring "catastrophe" but assuming it is binary (0 or 1), you can use this parameter as a categorical predictor. In running the regression analysis you can then tell whether or not the weather catastrophe is a significant predictor. If it is, then in your analysis you can compare predictions for the export given a catastrophe and without a catastrophe. I believe this is the risk in which you were hoping to measure in your forecasts.

```
forecast <- lm(export ~ predictor + weather, data)
summary(forecast)
new1 <- data.frame(predictor=--, weather=0)
new2 <- data.frame(predictor=--, weather=1)
predict(forecast, data=new1)
predict(forecast, data=new2)
```

Comment: Very nice explanation, To the point you have described

Comment: @Kaja this describes how to use data about weather catastrophes to make predictions about values. In your comment to the question you say that you do not have data about weather catastrophes. How can this be said to be best answer to your question?

Comment: @Lan_Fin as I said I have no data for weather catastrphe. There is a weather catastroohe or not?(1 or 0) and I would like to find the impact of this important parameter on my prediction. I found the answer very nice. What I was looking for. I must test it in detail :-)